# Does a PHP session work across subdirectories?

Tags: php, session

I have a main directory named `System` with a sub-directory named `Subsystem`. My session from main directory is not working in the sub-directory.

When I `echo session_save_path();` in both folders, they show me `"/tmp"`.

Then, I tried to put `session_save_path("../tmp");` in my sub-directory but it shows me `"This webpage has a redirect loop"`.

`session.php` in `System` directory:

```
<?php
session_start( );

if (!($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid'];
}
?>
```

session.php in Sub-system folder:

```
<?php
session_save_path("../tmp");
session_start( );

if (!($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid'];
}
```

?>

I have Googled all over, but I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: @TheSmose, yes, commented under your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The directory does not affect your session state (all directories of a given Apache-PHP website will access the same session in a standard configuration).  You should not have to use `session_save_path()`.

I think the problem in part is that you're setting 'uid' to itself (`$_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid'];`) - therefore potentially never actually setting it to a value - and potentially redirecting indefinitely if it's not set.

I suggest this simple test to ensure that your sessions are, in fact, working:

**/session_set.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = 123;
```

**/sub_dir/session_get.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['uid'];
```

Comment: this testing is working, the sub-folder can get the session from main folder. My session is created in login.php after user has successfully logged in. Thus, i pass the session thru session.php in the main folder. but my subfolder doesn't get the session still :(

Comment: By the way, ($_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid'];) just works fine among pages in the main directory.

Comment: @Newbie - It'll work fine anywhere, but it's not doing anything.  The problems you're having are not due to the session.  There's a problem somewhere else in your logic.  I suggest you create a new question posting all your session logic and let someone figure out where the bug is.

Comment: I have this problem too! Please do help. I am upvoting this question

Answer (score 0):

A session creates a file in a temporary directory on the server where registered session variables and their values are stored. This data will be available to all pages on the site during that visit.

The location of the temporary file is determined by a setting in the php.ini file called session.save_path. so pleasse check this path.

Also [session-save-path()][1] Get and/or set the current session save path.

I think u dont need to write this line and check your php.ini for correct path.

for session i found some useful article http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

Thanks.

Comment: in php.ini (in public/html folder), i found session.save_path = "/tmp". then wat should i do? i wonder is it something wrong with the seesion_save_path or not.